# Need to retrieve particular parts of the string with some conditions and then it should be updated in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and values like this

```
`create table bxtable(pack varchar(250),outputs varchar(250))

insert into bxtable(pack) values('1BG/10BX')
insert into bxtable(pack) values('1BG/1BX')
insert into bxtable(pack) values('1BG/2BX')
insert into bxtable(pack) values('1BG/8BX/8PK/4000CS')
insert into bxtable(pack) values('1BK/6BX')
insert into bxtable(pack) values('1BO/10BX')
insert into bxtable(pack) values('1BO/12BX')
insert into bxtable(pack) values('1BO/1BX')
insert into bxtable(pack) values('1BO/2BX')
`
```

I need to get the output like this, i.e extract the string related to bx only as shown in the fig
[image]

Comment: i tried to do like this but not getting much idea  SELECT pack,LEFT(SUBSTRING(pack,
                      CHARINDEX('/', pack) + 1, 100),
                      CHARINDEX('BX', pack) - 1)
FROM bxtable

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `REPLACE`, `SUBSTRING` & `CHARINDEX` functions as next:-

```
Update bxtable
set outputs = REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(pack, CHARINDEX('/', pack) + 1
, CHARINDEX('BX',pack) - CHARINDEX('/', pack) + Len('BX')),'BX',''),'/','')
```

Result:-

```
Select * from bxtable
```

[image]

**UPDATE 1:-**

For covering case `100BX/12B`, use the next code instead of above:-

```
Update bxtable
set outputs = 
CASE 
        WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(pack, CHARINDEX('/', pack) + 1
        , CHARINDEX('BX',pack) - CHARINDEX('/', pack) + Len('BX')),'BX',''),'/','') = ''
    Then  
        Left(pack, CHARINDEX('/', pack) -3)
    Else 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(pack, CHARINDEX('/', pack) + 1
    , CHARINDEX('BX',pack) - CHARINDEX('/', pack) + Len('BX')),'BX',''),'/','') 
End
```

**UPDATE 2:-**

For covering the case that have more than `/`, we should use `REVERSE` function, as next:-

```
Update bxtable
set outputs = 
CASE 
        WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(pack, CHARINDEX('/', pack) + 1
        , CHARINDEX('BX',pack) - CHARINDEX('/', pack) + Len('BX')),'BX',''),'/','') = ''
    Then  
        Left(pack, CHARINDEX('/', pack) -3)
    Else 
        RIGHT(LEFT(pack,CHARINDEX('BX',pack) -1 )
        ,CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE('/' + LEFT(pack,CHARINDEX('BX',pack) -1 ))) - 1)
End
```

Comment: but it wont give 100 if the inserted value is like this  insert into bxtable(pack) values('100BX/12B')

Comment: @navs waiting ur feedback.

Comment: it works pretty well, but IT WONT GIVE 400 FOR insert into bxtable(pack) values('1EA/100BG/400BX')

Comment: IT WONT HOLDS GOOD FOR THIS AS WELL insert into bxtable(pack) values('1EA/10BG/1000BX')

Comment: Why you are SHOUTING me in your comment?

Comment: @navs Never mind, plz check the update2 section, and feel free for notify me with any other comments.

Comment: Hi ahmed abdelqader thanks for your time, that is a perfect code, thanks a  lot for your help, My code, i.e usage of parsename comes handy when it has upto 4 /'s, but your code works fine for all combinations

Comment: @navs, If the answer meets ur requirements, kindly accept the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
update bxtable set outputs = substring(pack, charindex('/', pack) + 1, 
    charindex('BX', pack) - charindex('/', pack) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE bxtable
        SET outputs =
     SUBSTRING((SUBSTRING(pack,CHARINDEX('/',pack)+1,Len(pack))),0,CHARINDEX('BX',(SUBSTRING(pack,CHARINDEX('/',pack)+1,Len(pack))))) AS outputs
     FROM bxtable
```

OutPut

```
pack                |outputs
 --------------------------------
1BG/10BX            |10
1BG/1BX             |1
1BG/2BX             |2
1BG/8BX/8PK/4000CS  |8
1BK/6BX             |6
1BO/10BX            |10
1BO/12BX            |12
1BO/1BX             |1
1BO/2BX             |2
```

Comment: thanks for your time, but it won't work for all combinations please check my previous comments with ahmed abdelqader

Answer (score 0):

I think my code will work better

```
`WITH CTEA (pack,A)
AS
(
select * from (select pack, parsename(replace(pack,'/','.'),1)AS A FROM bxtable
union all
select pack,parsename(replace(pack,'/','.'),2)AS A FROM bxtable 
union all
select pack,parsename(replace(pack,'/','.'),3)AS A FROM bxtable 
union all
select pack,parsename(replace(pack,'/','.'),4) AS A FROM bxtable 
union all
select pack,parsename(replace(pack,'/','.'),5)AS A FROM bxtable ) t 
where a like '%BX%'
)
SELECT pack,SUBSTRING( A , 1, CHARINDEX('B',A)-1) AS  [BX VALUE] FROM CTEA`
```

but if any easy/alternate way will be appreciated more